# Rails3 custom generators ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, generator

I've inherited a specific generators and edited the method, so that a spec for _form is created. There's the solution:

```
# lib/generators/rspec_modded/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb
require 'generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb'
module RspecModded
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Rspec::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator
      def generate_view_specs
        super
        copy_view :_form
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I do `rails g` rspec_modded:scaffold is in list and actually work if called manually (`rails g rspec_modded:scaffold test`).

```
# config/application.rb
# ...
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec_modded, :fixture => false, fixture_replacement: nil
  g.fallbacks[:rspec_modded] = :rspec
end
```

For what I know, every `hook_for :test_framework` should call rspec_modded generator and rspec should manage what I haven't (such as model). But it doesn't work: for some reason the unit_test generator kick in! What the matter? I really don't understand...

PS: I'm using rails 3.2.6

Answer (score 0):

After a LOT of digging and tries, I've founded that `factory_girl_rails` gem was the culprit of this strange behavior!
The problem is in file `lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb`, it has an initializer that check if rspec is the test_framework and if wasn't, bruteforce to unit_test -_-

And know I see they have fixed it...

However, why this configuration overwrite the user defined one? I think this one should have the highest priority... Someone can clarify it?

---

After another bit of digging, seems that putting the code for generators in an initializer overwrite the user one, but if that piece of code is in the body of Railtie class definition, all works well...